# Is it possible to breakdown the error.path message part by part in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

In jsonSchema validator when I am using the below code:

```
for error in errors:
    print("Error:{}.".format(error_count))
    print(error.path)
```

It shows the below result:

```
Error:1.
['ID', 5801, 'name', 'address', 0, 'postal_code']
```

can I fetch the index number only. For example 5801 only in this case?

Comment: `print(error.path[1])`?

Comment: Thanks I tried to do print(list(error.path[1])) and it shows error.  You one is perfect. thanks